# How do you get the Mozzila Firefox Beta?

Tags: 13.04, firefox

64 bit. Title explains it all. Just want Firefox beta.

Comment: I found your question helpful because I was under the impression that 64-bit was only available for Firefox nightly builds. While that seems to be true for Windows, Linux and Mac users aren't affected!

Comment: @vasa1 Yeah me too.